# Mysql Count() not working

Tags: mysql

**students_records**

```
+----+-----+-----+-------+
| Sr | SRN | ARN | Marks |
+----+-----+-----+-------+
| 1  | ge  | aj  |  10   |
| 2  | ge  | bd  |   4   |
+----+-----+-----+-------+
```

From the above database, I want to count the number of **Rows** having Marks **less than '<='** 5 and having ARn value **not equal to '!='" N. So for the above example the count should be **1** but with my codes it is **2**.

Code:

```
SELECT COUNT(Sr) AS Sr FROM students_records WHERE ARN != 'N' AND Marks <= '5'
```

Comment: Can you tell `$ua` and `$mr` values are?

Comment: make marks a numeric field, not varchar

Comment: @Rafee the question is edited!

Comment: If I run that query against that table I get the correct result. Can you run `DESCRIBE students_records` to show us your table structure?

Comment: `Marks + 0 <= 5`

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ok, but if it is varchar then is there any solution, as new queries are inserted at any time...

Comment: @SimonBrahan `Marks` field is having a type `varchar` also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470530/mysql-pdo-count-not-working#comment81895732_47470530)

Comment: @Forward Can I get explanation of using `+ 0 <= 5`

Comment: Or `Marks <= 5`, this will implict convert varchar to int.

Comment: @Forward , you mean to say removing ``' '`` will do my work?

Comment: You can try and check.

Comment: Marks <= '5' is compared as string

Comment: @YourCommonSense As you edited my question, is this a wrong method using .....`ARN LIKE '" . $ua . "'`...... ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Any update with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470530/mysql-count-not-working/47470760#comment81896564_47470530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should change the field type to integer as that's what's being stored. If that is not possible you can cast the field at query time like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(Sr) AS Sr FROM t WHERE ARN != 'N' AND cast(Marks AS UNSIGNED) <= '5';
```

But this is likely to be slow as you get a larger data set.

You can also perform the cast implicitly by removing the quote marks surrounding `"5"` like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(Sr) AS Sr FROM t WHERE ARN != 'N' AND Marks <= 5;
```

Comment: **But this is likely to ....** , you mean to say the process will be slow as compared to changing the type to integer?

Comment: @PBMusics That's right. Storing the value as the correct type means less processing when you run the query.

Comment: Ok, for I will go for the second query mentioned by you, and will keep in mind that thing. But doing this way, there is no chance of error or there are?

Comment: As long as `Marks` only ever contains strings that look like integers, you should be fine. If that is the case though, you should definitely change the column type.

Comment: If all the values in `Marks` are integers, you should make the column an `int` column. That case.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for spending your valuable time for my silly doubt. [A last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470530/mysql-count-not-working/47470760#comment81896564_47470530)

Comment: I can't help there as I don't know what the original looked like. Your Common Sense does know PDO very well though, so his recommendation was probably helpful. He has a few links on his profile that may give you more information.

Comment: Sorry to disturb can you please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485738/how-do-i-remove-pma-tables-from-mysql-without-affecting-other-tables

Answer (score 0):

The only real solution here is to change the field type of `marks` from `varchar` to a number data type like `integer`.

An ugly workaround is

```
where cast(marks as unsigned) <= 5
```

Comment: Agree, but can you also please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470530/mysql-count-not-working#comment81895732_47470530)

Comment: Sorry to disturb can you please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485738/how-do-i-remove-pma-tables-from-mysql-without-affecting-other-tables