# How do I remove pma tables from mysql without affecting other tables

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a problem with my phpMyAdmin installation. I accidentally clicked something that creates the **pma** tables used by phpMyAdmin. (Probably advance features).

[[image: See Image]1]

I have some Questions:

1. Does this affect other tables?
2. What is the use of this table?
3. How can I completely disable **advanced features** in phpMyAdmin and so remove these **pma** tables?

Comment: No, it will not affect any of your code/query. You should not delete them.

Comment: @urfusion Thanks for the response, if I want to delete them how should I?

Comment: these table contains information ragrding `phpmyadmin` and their configuration. Why do you want to delete them?

Comment: @urfusion There many tables and it get confused, so I want to delete them, and keep my database as it was earlier...

Comment: Leave it as it as and create your own `DB` and use it.

Comment: @urfusion It is in the `DB` that's why...

Comment: it is in `phpmyadmin` you can create your separate `DB`

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/enable-phpmyadmins-extra-features/

Comment: @urfusion I have that in my own database [see this](https://imgur.com/ZvTj7wL)

Comment: There is something wrong with your `DB`. Use `DROP` query to drop your DB.

Comment: @urfusion which tables should I drop?

Comment: drop whole `DB` and check your sql for `pma` table.

Comment: @urfusion Should I take backup only of my tables? and not of PMA?

Comment: Yes, Take backup of whole DB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

phpMyAdmin offers to create these tables for you to store configuration information for advanced functionality of the program. The tables are optional. Usually they're put in the 'phpmyadmin' database, but in the event that you don't have permission to create a new database the tables can be put in the database to which you do have access. Based on your comments, that seems to be what happened here.

You can remove them through any of the usual means to remove a table — either from each table itself go to the Operations tab and click the "Delete the table (DROP)" link, or go to the database Structure tab, select the ones that start with 'pma__', and pick 'Drop' from the "With selected:" dropdown box.

There's a chance that you'll run in to an error caused by it trying to write to the history table after you've removed that one, in that case logging out and logging back in should clear the error for you.

To answer your other questions:

> Does this affect other tables?

No, the operation of each table is rather independent of each other.

> What is the use of this table?

Various phpMyAdmin features like a graphical table relation editor, query history and bookmarks, and user preferences.

> How can I completely disable advanced features in phpMyAdmin and so remove these pma tables?

Simply remove the tables. To completely remove any warning about the missing tables, you can edit the `config.inc.php` file to add  `$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;`
and to disable the possibility of automatically creating these add `$cfg['ZeroConf'] = false;`

Comment: #IT WORKS!.     I'm in Shock, because all my database